# Get MAX value from two tables

Tags: postgresql

Using [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) and I have two tables (users & live_user_data) with a unique ID to join between the two, both tables have the user ID, but one has a user level (null and 1 to 50).

live_user_data contains every instance a user's level was recorded, so it contains hundreds of thousands of instances, so when do a simple join query, I get every level result for every user. What I'd like is to get results that shows just a list of all users with the max value for their user_level.

table: users

```
id  system_id user_id
1 001 John Smith
2 002 Jacob Smith
3 001 John Smith
4 003 Steve Smith
5 002 Jacob Smith
```

table: live_user_data

```
system_id level
002 1
002 7
001 10
003 4
002 15
```

Comment: Try max with join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the two tables and use a Group By construct

```
SELECT users.id, users.systemid, MAX(live_user_data.level)
FROM   users
           LEFT OUTER JOIN live_user_data
              ON users.system_id = live_user_data.system_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.systemid
```